# inappbrowser javascript injection phonegap build 3.7

Tags: cordova, inject, inappbrowser

I am programming my first app and using Phonegap Build 3.7 most of my app is hosted in a php server and i use Inappbrowser as a UI. My question is i have some googleads that i want to open in a new window when clicked and not the same webview inside Inappbrowser, i know that you can use "_system" while still "inside the app" but as soon as Inappbrowser is launched acts as a standalone browser. Is it possible to inject a javascript i.e. "phonegap.js" from you local file and use window.open('blabla' '_system') to correct this issue? Many thanks in advance, i hope i made myself clear as i am just starting.
BTW does anyone know the exact location of the "phonegap.js" or "cordova.js" in Android or IOS apps?

Answer (score 3):

Cordova Inappbrowser provides  `executeScript()`  to inject javascript to external page after the load get finished.

```
// Global InAppBrowser reference
var iabRef = null;

    function InjectScript() {
        iabRef.executeScript({
            code: "      /* Your code here */       "
        }, function() {
            alert("Code added");
        });
    }


iabRef = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');

iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', InjectScript);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ok let me see if i can get this right, (like i said i am just starting Phonegap)this code goes in the php page that opens inside Inappbrowser correct? And then from there onwards i can open links is system browser?